# Route [RemindersController@postRemind] not defined error in Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel-4, forgot-password

I was implementing Laravel's password reminded function but hitting this error:

`Route [RemindersController@postRemind]` not defined.

I am using Laravel 4 and absolutely new to Laravel.I used

```
php artisan auth:reminders-controller
```

to create `RemindersController`.

```
   <?php

   class RemindersController extends Controller {

  public function getRemind()
  {
    return View::make('password_remind');
  }

public function postRemind()
{

   Password::remind(Input::only('email'), function($message)
  {
     $message->subject('Password Reminder');
  });                
}

public function getReset($token = null)
{
    if (is_null($token)) App::abort(404);

    return View::make('password.reset')->with('token', $token);
}

public function postReset()
{
    $credentials = Input::only(
        'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
    );

    $response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);

        $user->save();
       });

       switch ($response)
       {
        case Password::INVALID_PASSWORD:
        case Password::INVALID_TOKEN:
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

        case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }
     }
   }
```

I created view `password_remind.blade.php` which is shown below :

```
 @extends('layouts.default_layout')
 @section('content')
     <div class="row" style="min-height: 376px">
       <div class="col-sm-4">
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-top: 70px;">
        <div class="login">
           <form action="{{action('RemindersController@postRemind')}}" method="POST">
               <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </form> 
        </div>
       </div> 
     </div>
 @stop
```

In root I added   `Route::get('forgotPassword', 'RemindersController@getRemind');` 
  The url http://localhost/laravel_work/public/forgotPassword gives

`Route [RemindersController@postRemind]` not defined

error.
Where am I wrong ? I cannot find the mistake.Pls Help Me :(*

Comment: Try doing `composer dump`.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you. Can you make it more clear??? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, if you look at your form you have `action="{{action('RemindersController@postRemind')}}"`

But according to you, the only route you added was `RemindersController@getRemind`

I'm assuming you want just the **get** to quickly check the view right now, but maybe the `action()` is actually eagerly looking for that non-existent route.

Is your app dying when you post the form or when you get the view? Either way defining the route for the **post** like you did with the **get** should fix it.

Comment: is the following what you have?

`Route::get('forgotPassword', 'RemindersController@getRemind');
 Route::controller('forgotPassword', 'RemindersController');`

Comment: I added Route::post('forgotPassword/change', 'RemindersController@postRemind'); in route and changed action to action="{{ URL::to('forgotPassword/change') }}". Now the error has gone. :)

Comment: great! one of those two was the culprit :D

Comment: But nthing is coming in my mail :(